# Django: using html templates TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I've been writing my first Django app and hit a problem with using templates.

No matter how I format the url for the template I receive the TemplateDoesNotExist error.

My html is nest in `views/` with the core template being `views/template.html`.

I have tried:

`myapp/views/template.html`

`views/template.html`

`templates/views/template.html`

`<full path to app>/<all variations>`

None of which can locate the template.

I understand the TEMPLATE_DIRS variable may be set at project level but this is app-specific and the `views/` directory is not purely for templates.

I don't think I should add to the url_patterns since the template shouldn't be accessible directly.

I've got this far without them but need to clean up the app.

Any advice?

Edit:

The only line in my controller currently is:

`template = loader.get_template("test/templates/test/template.html")`

The line has been tested with every variation mentioned above and the one from the first comment.

There are no additional lines added to the urlpatterns, as I understand it adding to here would open access up to the public via url.

Comment: If you do not specify the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable, it should be stored in `myapp/templates/myapp/template.html`. and you refer it as `app/template.html`.

Comment: Are you sure you're correctly rendering the path to template in your `views.py`? Can you provide code for your views.py, urls.py, and you're path structure?

Comment: @RickyKim. I've added the only line in the controller currently which is throwing the error.

Comment: Why is your template in a "views" directory? In Django, "views" means what you are calling the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be:

`template = loader.get_template("test/template.html")`